# Benefits of using DoubleClick when having adverts sold by an agency anyways

Tags: advertising, tracking, google-dfp

All my display ads are sold through an agency (direct sales and AdX). I'm getting a high CPM and everything is fine. However, I only get a report at the end of the month with all the figures. So I though of setting up a DoubleClick for Publishers account myself and track at least the views and CTR myself, by just dropping in the agencies [Adition](https://www.adition.com) adverts code into my DoubleClick account.

Would that work with DoubleClick? Would just dropping in the Adition code work or is there a better way to connect them (and maybe even exchange some information like CPM)?

Comment: It would work for the impressions. Third party serving codes may not have the option to track clicks in DFP.